# Boundedness of Riemann zeta function: for every $a>1$ there is $\frac{1}{a-1} \le \zeta(a) \le \frac{a}{a-1}$

Tags: analysis, riemann-zeta

I've got a question. How to prove that for every $a>1$ there is
$\frac{1}{a-1} \le \zeta(a) \le \frac{a}{a-1}$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $a>1$ we have:
$$ \zeta(a)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(a)}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{a-1}}{e^{x}-1}\,dx$$ 
but if $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$, $\frac{1}{e^x-1}\geq\frac{1}{x e^{x}}$, from which the inequality $\zeta(a)\geq\frac{1}{a-1}$ readily follows.

On the other hand, we also have the inequality $\frac{1}{e^{x}-1}\leq \frac{1}{x e^{x/2}}$, from which it follows that:
$$ \zeta(a)\leq \frac{2^{a-1}}{a-1},$$
that is stronger than the given inequality for $a\in (1,2)$.

As an alternative, we also have:
$$\zeta(a)= \frac{1}{1^a}+\frac{1}{2^a}+\ldots \geq \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x^a} = \frac{1}{a-1}$$
and:
$$\zeta(a)-1= \frac{1}{2^a}+\frac{1}{3^a}+\ldots\leq \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x^a} = \frac{1}{a-1}$$
since $\frac{1}{x^a}$ is a decreasing and convex function on $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: That must be true, but the thing is I can't use the first equality you've written. It has to be proved by some basics inequalities and features of improper intergrals.

Comment: @janusz These are basic inequalities and this is an improper integral.

Comment: The "alternative" establishes the requested bounds precisely (not tighter ones) and in an elementary way.  So, +1

Comment: Still have one question, how do we know that this inequalities are true? Sorry for so much questions :D